# R shiny pickerinput choicesOpt

Tags: r, shiny, pickerinput

This is a simple question: I'm having a hard time finding a documentation of what can go into the `choicesOpt` argument of `pickerInput`. I've tried Google, Stackoverflow and most of the doc-sites I know and tried looking in the source of the package yet haven't found anything. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

`choicesOpt` argument is useful to apply formatting to the inputs of `pickerInput`.

For example to give background to the options of `pickerInput` you can do :

```
library(shiny)
cols <- c('blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow')
ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("col", "Colour", choices = cols, 
              choicesOpt = list(style = sprintf('background:%s;', cols)))
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select picker Input Control, i.e. the `pickerInput` is built on top of `bootstrap-select`, documentation for all the options is [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: In the options section there are options listed that can either go into the `options` argument (like `hideDisabled`) or into the `choicesOpt` argument (like `style`). How do I know where to put which?